# Android Compose Textfield handle backspace(delete)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is in compose any way to handle delete(backspace) action in keyboard?
I want to handle the delete action in keyboard

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087402/how-to-handle-key-events-during-textfield-editing-in-compose) answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

```
modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.key == Key.Delete) {
            // Action When Click on Delete
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
     }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: According to the documentation: "This callback is invoked when the user interacts with the **hardware** keyboard"

Comment: `Key.Delete` does not seems to work, but `Key.Backspace` does.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across `Key.Backspace` vs `Key.Delete`

Documentation says

```
Backspace key.
Deletes characters before the insertion point, unlike Delete.
```

and

```
Delete key.
Deletes characters ahead of the insertion point, unlike [Backspace].
```

I try it in my own words: `Backspace key` is triggered when you remove the character left from your cursor. `Delete` is triggered when you remove the character right from your cursor.